# Not sure where to screw the graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I am going to buy a Nvidia GeForce GT 730 for my PC. I opened the case and did some checks. The motherboard has a PCI express x16 slot. But it seems the graphics card must be screwed to keep it firm. I am not sure where to screw. Here is the picture of my case:

[image: Case]

Should I screw the video card here?

[image: Should I screw the video card here]

Also, will the video card fit in the space?

Comment: Take down the metal plate from **1.** and insert your graphics card. It should fit there. That metal plate should have a screw at the top to take it down, **2**.
 http://image.prntscr.com/image/9a55578168434d53b5db8fb99bcbe4d9.png

Answer (score 3):

Your case may not have screws hard to see from pic remove the plate inline with the slot

[image]

Comment: Iam asking this just to make sure.  Can the video card i mentioned fit in the given space.

Comment: You can find the graphics card length in the technical specs. Which exact graphics card brand/model are you going to buy?

Comment: S.Srihari, whether or not the card fits depends on both the card and the case. Check the specs for your card to get the length, then check to specs for the case to see if it can accommodate the card (or vice versa)

Comment: Looks like your case doesn't have screws but uses a different system to secure your cards, it might be a TOOL-FREE case, with a long bracket that covers all the spaces or something similar, that bracket should have a lock/lever or thumb-screw at one of the sides, so you can remove it, place your card and then secure it again. http://i.imgur.com/eZtdamW.jpg